# Unable to call function defined in a separate file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function `login` defined in a file `index.js`:

```
function login(un, pass){
    ....
}
```

In my `index.html`, I have:

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    ....
    <script>
        ....
        login("user", "pass");
    </script>
    ....
</body>
```

But this gives me the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined

Both `index.html` and `index.js` are in the same folder. What am I missing here?

### EDIT

One crucial detail I missed out was that I was hosting this using a Flask server. After some research, I realised that the `js` file has to be in a folder named `static`.

Comment: This seems fine. Can you check that the index.js file is included properly, using your browser's developer tools (usually F12 > Network tab)?

Comment: Is `login` function global in `index.js`? Also, there must not be syntax errors in the function definition. If the script is OK, then it is never loaded, check the Network tab in the Dev Tools.

Comment: I used your code, and its working fine for me

Comment: Maybe script `src` is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

As a better practise, another way to achieve this in EcmaScript 6, is to simply define the function and ['export'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) it as a module. You can then ['import'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the module from another Javascript file or within the HTML  tags as seen below, ensuring the path to files are accurate:

./src/index.js:

```
var login = function (user, pass) { ... }

export { login };
```

index.html:

```
<script>
    import login from './src/index'
    ...
    login ("user", "pass");
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions of "index.js" maybe it is not accessible?

Also try referring to it as

```
<script src="../yourFolder/index.js"></script>
```